# Bash script array loop in EOF of "here document"

Tags: bash, shell, heredoc

Am trying to loop an array in "here document" be used with expect for certbot:

```
myArray+=( "sub1.domain.org" "sub2.domain.org" )
echo ${myArray[@]}

expect <(cat << EOF
    certbot --apache \
    "${myArray[@]}"
    for val in \"${myArray[@]}"; do
        -d \"${val}"
    done
EOF
)
```

the final result should be:

```
certbot --apache -d sub1.domain.org -d sub2.domain.org
```

Then i have to respond with expect https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect to the questions, but my loop doesn't work.

Comment: expect uses tcl for its scripting, not shell/bash. It's not going to understand that.

Comment: What do you expect (pun not intended) `expect` to do here? It should be treated as somewhat of a last resort; many commands provide non-interactive ways to specify data that you would ordinarily provide in an interactive session.

Comment: If `expect cerbot --apache -d ...` would work, then the easiest thing to do will be to build up a second array (`cmd=(certbot --apache); ...`), then running `expect "${cmd[@]}"`.

Comment: Hey @chepner this sounds interesting, can you please give me full example? (to keep it easy, let's leave expect and "EOF here document" out, because all i need is just the loop for the certbot subdomains)

Answer (score 0):

Build a second array to contain the arguments for `certbot`:

```
args=(--apache)
for val in "${myArray[@]}"; do
    args+=(-d "$val")
done

cerbot "${args[@]}"
```